# Is it possible for collisions to occur in md5 for inputs in the range 0 to 2^32 - 1?

Tags: mysql, hash

I am generating a transaction ID that users will see on printouts of their transactions. The transaction ID is an md5 hash of the value of the auto increment column 'id' of a mysql database(type int). This limits the size of 'id' column to a maximum of 2^32 - 1 (=4294967295) and a minimum of 1. Is it possible there is a collision in that range?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [md5 hash collisions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885667/md5-hash-collisions)

Comment: Considering how fast MD5 is, you can definitely try this for at least 100 million values.  Or, you could use a transaction id based partly on timestamp.  e.g.  `20170125111234`   as in `yyyymmddhhxxxx` where xxxx is your `id` column modulo 10000.   Notice that git uses the leading eight or ten digits of an SHA hash to identify commits.